# What is the most efficient manner to use MIN,MAX transaction dates - and getting amounts of these individual transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I want to display the first, last transactions of our users, and display these amounts. This can be done by

```
 SELECT user, min(Date) firstDate, max(Date) lastDate
   INTO #MinAndMax
   FROM transactionTable
  GROUP BY user
```

Then I do another inner select statement, to get the amount based on the value obtained above when doing the min(Date), so like the following;

```
 SELECT (SELECT amount
           FROM transactionTable
          WHERE date = firstDate) AS firstAmount
   FROM #MinAndMax
```

However is there a more efficient manner to do this, like pivoting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If might be faster to use analytic functions to rank your transactions by user, and select the first for each:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  [User], 
            FirstDate = Date, 
            FirstAmount = Amount, 
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY Date),
            LastDate = MAX(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY [User])
    FROM    TransactionTable
)
SELECT  [User], FirstDate, FirstAmount, LastDate
FROM    CTE
WHERE   RowNum = 1;
```

If, as in your query you only need the amount, your query could simply be. If you have a user table, then it might be faster still to use [`APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) along with `TOP`:

```
SELECT  u.[User], FirstAmount = t.Amount
FROM    Users u
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 Amount
            FROM    TransactionTable t
            WHERE   t.[User] = u.[User]
            ORDER BY t.Date
        ) t;
```

---

**EDIT**

To get the first and last amounts you would need a second `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  [User], 
            Date, 
            Amount, 
            RowNumAsc = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY Date),
            RowNumDesc = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY Date DESC)
    FROM    TransactionTable
)
SELECT  [User], 
        FirstDate = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNumAsc = 1 THEN Date END), 
        FirstAmount = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNumAsc = 1 THEN Amount END),
        LastDate = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNumDesc = 1 THEN Date END),
        LastAmount = MIN(CASE WHEN RowNumDesc = 1 THEN Amount END) 
FROM    CTE
WHERE   1 IN (RowNumAsc, RowNumDesc)
GROUP BY [User];
```

Or

```
SELECT  u.[User], 
        FirstDate = f.Date,
        FirstAmount = f.Amount,
        LastDate = l.Date,
        LastAmount = l.Amount
FROM    Users u
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 Amount, Date
            FROM    TransactionTable t
            WHERE   t.[User] = u.[User]
            ORDER BY t.Date
        ) AS f
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 Amount, Date
            FROM    TransactionTable t
            WHERE   t.[User] = u.[User]
            ORDER BY t.Date DESC
        ) AS l;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9801/6)**

Comment: Hi @Gareth I need the first, last time stamps, together with their amounts. So in this case I would need to query CTE twice? Once for the first, and another for the second?

Comment: I mean, in your answer, you show the FirstAmount. If I want to show the LastAmount? I cannot use LastAmount = (amount) over (partition by user order by Date desc)... How could I include that?

Comment: Both queries posted in the edit should give you the first and last transactions per user. `PARTITION BY User` inside the `ROW_NUMBER` function ensures it is reset to 1 for each new user. I have added an SQL Fiddle to demonstrate the output of each query.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Gareth - and very well explained!